# bcmwl-kernel-source crashes on start up

Tags: drivers, kernel, lubuntu, compiling, broadcom

Not able to get my wifi driver working this is the error.

```
Tue Dec  8 21:42:33 IST 2020
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_dev_ioctl’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:462:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_fs’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  set_fs(get_ds());
         ^~~~~~
         get_fs
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:462:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/fpu/xstate.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h:26,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:99,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/include/linuxver.h:65,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:26:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_pci_probe’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:780:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if ((val & 0x0000ff00) != 0)
  ^~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:782:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
   bar1_size = pci_resource_len(pdev, 2);
   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:40:0:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_set_auth_type’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.h:52:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  if (wl_dbg_level & WL_DBG_DBG) {   \
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:816:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘WL_DBG’
   WL_DBG(("network eap\n"));
   ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:817:2: note: here
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:273: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1757: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build' failed
```

I tried re installing linux-generic, linux-headers, purge and reinstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` still face this error please help me with this.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on the same kernel. Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: And how do you install the driver? Is it from the repos? Did you run `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: Indeed. Why not simply: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y bcmwl-kernel-source`. There is no need to compile from source.

Comment: I did install from apt the log I showed is from /var/crash